# How to make the node_modules folder accessible during the build process of a ui5 themelib?

Tags: sapui5, ui5-tooling

I want to build an open UI5 theme-library using the ui5 tooling (CLI).
This is normally no problem, but I want to build it using an other UI5 theme-library which I installed via npm and which resided in the node_modules directory.

During the build process after executing

```
ui5 build --config ui/ui5.yaml
```

I get the error message, that the .less file from the node_modules directory can't be found:

> Error Message: Could not find file at path
> '/resources/node_modules/@my-company/imported-ui-themelib/dist/resources/sap/ui/core/themes/mytheme/library.source.less'

I tried to include the file this way:

```
@import "../../../../../node_modules/@my-company/imported-ui-themelib/dist/resources/sap/ui/core/themes/mytheme/library.source.less";
```

in a library.source.less file which is located in the directory:

```
ui/themelib-custom/src/sap/ui/core/themes/mythemecustom/library.source.less
```

The .less file in the node_modules directory is installed and I copied the relative path to make sure there are no typos. But somehow the runtime of the build process does not include the node_modules folder to be accessible.

Can anyone help? How can i make the node_modules folder accessible during the build process of my ui5 themelib? Maybe somehow in the ui5.yaml config file?

Would be very thankful for any help!

Thanks in advance

Florian